# Getting Serialization exception while consuming from Kafka queue using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Boot with Kafka to consume messages from Kafka queue.

However, if there is any error in Jackson parsing of the payload.

The message remains stuck and it keeps on re-attempting for consumption, giving parsing exception all the time.

I tried using ErrorHandlingDeserializer2 in Kafka configuration and also mapped error handler, but still, the problem persists.

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig 
{

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.class);
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, StringDeserializer.class);

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.class);
        props.put(ErrorHandlingDeserializer2.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS, JsonDeserializer.class);

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "${connecto.group-id}");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, UserDto> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                consumerConfigs(),
                new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(UserDto.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, UserDto> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, UserDto> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());

        factory.setErrorHandler(new MosaicKafkaErrorHandler());

        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate() 
    {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, UserSearchDto> producerFactory() 
    {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        config.put(JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
    }
}

public class MosaicKafkaErrorHandler implements ContainerAwareErrorHandler{

@Override
public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer,
        MessageListenerContainer container) {
    thrownException.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

I want to have it implemented in a way where whenever a paring exception occurs then it should just log that message and proceed with next record rather than getting stuck with it.

Following is the error-

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.gxxx.mxxx.common.dto.UserDetailsDto` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"field1":20000,"field2":20000,"type":""}')

at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1230)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1187)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1154)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:741)
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:698)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition kafakaqueue.identify-1 at offset 326355379. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
```

Comment: We faced the same issue. Solution depends on your kafka version. Please let me know which version you are using.

Comment: show this `MosaicKafkaErrorHandler` code

Comment: `public class MosaicKafkaErrorHandler implements ContainerAwareErrorHandler{

 @Override
 public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer,
   MessageListenerContainer container) {
  thrownException.printStackTrace();
  
 }

}`

Comment: @Deadpool - only logging the error

Comment: can you update the code in the post @DhruvSaksena

Comment: @Deadpool - Done

Comment: @ManishBansal - Kafka version is 2.0.1

Comment: what is your spring-kafka version? and why don't you simply use `ConsumerAwareErrorHandler` instead of `ContainerAwareErrorHandler` @DhruvSaksena

Comment: @DhruvSaksena Can you also share the stacktrace which you got inside handle method.

Comment: @Deadpool - Iam using Spring Boot-2.1.4.  with managed version of spring-kafka as 2.2.5.RELEASE

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To solve this problem, [version 2.2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer) introduced the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer2`. This deserializer delegates to a real deserializer (key or value). If the delegate fails to deserialize the record content, the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer2` returns a null value and a `DeserializationException` in a header that contains the cause and the raw bytes. When you use a record-level `MessageListener`, if the ConsumerRecord contains a `DeserializationException` header for either the key or value, the container’s ErrorHandler is called with the failed ConsumerRecord. The record is not passed to the listener.

However, since you are using an earlier version, you can use below hack.

```
     @Override
        public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer,
                MessageListenerContainer container) {
            thrownException.printStackTrace();
            if (thrownException instanceOf SerializationException){
                String s = thrownException.getMessage().split("Error deserializing key/value for partition ")[1].split(". If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.")[0];
                String topics = s.split("-")[0];
                int offset = Integer.valueOf(s.split("offset ")[1]);
                int partition = Integer.valueOf(s.split("-")[1].split(" at")[0]);

                TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topics, partition);
                consumer.seek(topicPartition, offset + 1);  
               }
            }
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it's reaching the handler however collection of records is empty-

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0
        at java.util.Collections$EmptyList.get(Collections.java:4454) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at com.girnarsoft.mosaic.config.MosaicKafkaErrorHandler.handle(MosaicKafkaErrorHandler.java:22) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:852) [spring-kafka-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.5.RELEASE]
        at

Comment: @DhruvSaksena I have modified the code. It looks a bit hacky but can you please give it a try.

Comment: Sure Ive done the same. Please proceed with changes.

Comment: The handler is generic in nature. Can you please handle SerializationException specefically and indicate your answer.

Comment: How can I accept it?. I can't vote as my reputation is less than 15.

Comment: @DhruvSaksena Right beside my answer, where you can upvote the answer, you must see a transparent `right tick`. By clicking on it, it will turn green and answer will get accepted. Only the author of the question can see the `right tick`.

Comment: Done. Thanks again !!